# javamail - preserve format when replying to multi-part messages

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

When using Javamail API to iterate through messages, uncertain how to deal with multiple body parts.  When I reply to it I would like for the reply to look be formatted as the incoming message.

Comment: my advise is to avoid unnecessary introduction like that and provide us code.

Comment: updated to be more concise

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to separate the main body of the message from the attachments.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) to get started.  This will give you the plain text and/or html text of the message.

Next, you need to decide how you're going to edit the original message to include the text from the reply.  JavaMail doesn't help you with this.  Are you going to display the message to a user or are you going to edit the text programmatically?  Either way, this is likely to be the most difficult part unless you only deal with plain text messages.

Finally, with the new text, you can use the JavaMail Message.reply method to create the reply message and then set the content of the message using the edited text for the reply.  Note that it's more complicated if you want to support multipart/alternative messages with both a plain text and html part, and even more complicated if the html part is part of a multipart/related that includes images that it refers to.  An appropriate search will turn up many examples.

That's just a brief sketch of what's involved.  If you have more specific questions, show us your code.

Comment: Could you please share an example?

Comment: I don't have an example and I'm not going to write the code for you.  Give it a try and show us where you get stuck.  There's a bunch of working examples [here](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/tree/master/demo/src/main/java), but none that do everything you want.